# Perl: Getting complete request from SOAP::WSDL object

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl, http-request

I'm working with `SOAP::WSDL` and another company's custom WSDL file. Every time they make a change for me and I recreate my modules, something breaks. Finding the problem is rather tedious because I don't find a proper way to access the actual request that is sent to the SOAP server.

The only way to get to the request so far has been to use tcpdump in conjunction with wireshark to extract the request and result. That works, but since I don't have root privileges on the dev machine I have to get an admin over every time I want to do that. I feel there must be another way to get to the `HTTP::Request` object inside the `SOAP::WSDL` thing. But if the server returns a fault, I don't even have a response object, but rather a `SOAP::WSDL::SOAP::Typelib::Fault11` object that has no visible relation to the request.

I've also tried using the debugger but I'm having trouble finding the actual request part. I've not yet understood how to tell the debuger to skip to a specific part deep inside a complex number of packages.

Comment: Don't know the module, but have you tried to dump the whole object with Data::Dumper or Data::Dump? Just print Dumper $soap_res; ..

Comment: @ØyvindSkaar: That won't work because all the objects `SOAP::WSDL` creates are `Class::Std::Fast::Storable` objects. Dumpered they look like this: `$VAR1 = bless( do{\(my $o = 157)}, 'SOAP::WSDL::SOAP::Typelib::Fault11' );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to at least print out the generated XML code.

First, I looked at [SOAP::WSDL::Client](http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-WSDL-2.00.10/lib/SOAP/WSDL/Client.pm) as raina77ow suggested. That wasn't what I needed, though. But then I came across [SOAP::WSDL::Factory::Serializer](http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-WSDL-2.00.10/lib/SOAP/WSDL/Factory/Serializer.pm). There, it says:

> Serializer objects may also be passed directly to SOAP::WSDL::Client
>   by using the set_serializer method.

A little fidgeting and I came up with a wrapper class for [SOAP::WSDL::Serializer::XSD](http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-WSDL-2.00.10/lib/SOAP/WSDL/Serializer/XSD.pm) which is the default serializer used by [SOAP::WSDL](http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-WSDL-2.00.10/lib/SOAP/WSDL.pm). A look at the code helped, too.

Here's the module I wrote. It uses `SOAP::WSDL::Serializer::XSD` as a base class and overloads the `new` and `serialize` methods. While it only passes arguments to `new`, it grabs the returned XML from `serialize` and prints it, which suffices for debugging. I'm not sure if there's a way to put it somewhere I can easily get it from.

```
package MySerializer;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base qw(SOAP::WSDL::Serializer::XSD);

sub new {
  my $self = shift;
  my $class = ref($self) || $self;
  return $self if ref $self;

  # Create the base object and return it
  my $base_object = $class->SUPER::new(@_);
  return bless ($base_object, $class);
}

sub serialize {
  my ($self, $args_of_ref) = @_;

  # This is basically a wrapper function that calls the real Serializer's
  # serialize-method and grabs and prints the returned XML before it
  # giving it back to the caller

  my $xml = ref($self)->SUPER::serialize($args_of_ref);
  print "\n\n$xml\n\n"; # here we go
  return $xml;
}

1;
```

And here's how I call it:

```
my $serializer = MySerializer->new();
$self->{'_interface'} = Lib::Interfaces::MyInterface->new();
$self->{'_interface'}->set_serializer($serializer); # comment out to deactivate
```

It's easy to deactivate. Only put a comment in the `set_serializer` line.

Of course printing a block of XML to the command line is not very pretty, but it gets the job done. I only need it once in a while why coding/testing, so this is fine I guess.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/module/MKUTTER/SOAP-WSDL-2.00.99_3/lib/SOAP/WSDL/Transport/Loopback.pm

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled across this, having the same problem myself.  I found the answer is using both options that raina77ow listed.

```
$service->outputxml(1);
```

returns the whole SOAP envelope xml, but this needs to be combined with

```
$service->no_dispatch(1);
```

With no_dispatch set, the SOAP request is printed, instead of the reply from the request.  Hopefully this can help others.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use [SOAP::WSDL::Client](https://metacpan.org/module/SOAP%3a%3aWSDL%3a%3aClient) tracing methods - and [outputxml](https://metacpan.org/module/SOAP%3a%3aWSDL%3a%3aClient#outputxml) in particular? It returns the raw SOAP envelope which is to be sent to the server.

You can also use [no_dispatch](https://metacpan.org/module/SOAP%3a%3aWSDL#no_dispatch) configuration method of [SOAP::WSDL](https://metacpan.org/module/SOAP%3a%3aWSDL) package:

> When set, call() returns the plain request XML instead of dispatching
>   the SOAP call to the SOAP service. Handy for testing/debugging.

Comment: Interesting. That way I get the complete SOAP-Result XML. Not bad, but not helpful either, because I could get that by doing `$res->serialize` on the Fault-Result.

Comment: You led me onto the right track. Will post my own solution when the 8 hour restriction is up. Thanks. :)